# Are logarithms radicals?

Tags: logarithms, radicals

Does the set of all logarithms with a radical base and argument belong to the set of all radicals? A simple yes, no answer will suffice, an explanation would be wonderful.

EDIT 1
Can a logarithm with a base and argument expressible as "radical" be a root to a polynomial with integer coefficients when the root cannot be expressed as otherwise "radical"? Note that for this logarithm to be a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients, it cannot be transcendental.

Comment: What is your definition of "radical"?

Comment: good question. When I say radical I don't mean algebraic number, I mean number that is expressible by finite operations on an integer of multiplication subtraction addition division and exponentiation of integers and rationals

Comment: Exponentiation with what sort of exponent?

Comment: Your question is **not** about radicals in the accepted sense of the term, so I have removed the (radicals) tag.

Comment: So, it sounds like by "radical" you mean an element of the field
$$F=\mathbb{Q}(\{a^{1/r}:a,r\in\mathbb{N}\}),$$
or if you want to allow "radicals" of negative integers, an element of the larger field
$$L=F(\{e^{2\pi i/n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}).$$

Comment: Would it help to know that $\log(x)$ grows more slowly than $x^c$ for any $c > 0$?

Comment: the question seemed so simple when I first thought of it, now not so much.

"All numbers that can be obtained from the integers using a finite number of integer additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, and taking nth roots (where n is a positive integer) are algebraic." Is the wiki definition I am looking at that I am using

Comment: So basically you are asking if $\log_b x$ is algebraic if $b$ and $x$ are?

Comment: Or I guess not quite. Trying again: let $S = \{a^b \mid a, b \in \mathbb Q\}$. Is you question whether $b, x \in S$ implies $\log_b x \in S$?

Comment: almost, using algebraic numbers includes roots of polynomials larger than 5 with roots that cannot be expressed with finite operations. like the roots to $x^5 - x - 1$

Comment: I would say no; I'm sure e.g. $\log_2(3)$ is transcendental, but I don't know how to formally prove that. **EDIT:** Zev posted a very pretty proof. :)

Comment: very pretty proof, but because I cant quite articulate my question properly its not QUITE the answer to what I want as the proof involves transcendentals. I'll try and rephrase the question again here, if it makes more sense I will edit original post: Can a logarithm with a base and argument expressible as "radical" be a root to a polynomial with integer coefficients when the root cannot be expressed as otherwise "radical"?

Comment: @RobArthan : What do you mean by "radicals in the accepted sense of the term"?  I would take that to mean things like $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt[3] 2$, etc.  It appears to me that that _is_ what the question is about. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Rory: It certainly ***can*** be, for example $\log_2(8)=3$ and the numbers $2$, $8$, and $3$ are all "radical" according to your meaning. My post makes the point that *not all such* logarithms are radical, by proving that in fact sometimes such logarithms are transcendental numbers.

Comment: Transcendental numbers cannot be the root of a finite polynomial with integer coefficients. Can a bunch of factors on order of $$(x+log_a(b))$$ expand to have integer coefficients. a and be being "radicals" and $log_a(b)$ not being able to be expressed otherwise as a "radical".

Comment: @Rory: I interpret your original post as asking this: **Let $R$ be the set of "radical numbers", for some appropriate interpretation of that term. Is it true that $\{\log_a(b):a,b\in R\}$ is a subset of $R$?** I have demonstrated for you an example where $\log_2(3)$ is not an element of $R$, under what I consider a reasonable interpretation of "radical". What have I misunderstood about your question?

Comment: It answers the original question, just not the one I want it to :)

Comment: @MichaelHardy: the question as originally asked did not make any sense and it isn't much better now after several edits. Logarithms of algebraic numbers are not in general algebraic numbers. What the OP means by "all radicals" is very unclear. Hence my close vote - the OP has done nothing to clarify the question.

Comment: @RoryGrice : Please: It's $\log_a(b)$, not $log_a(b)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's say by "radical" you mean an element of the field
$$\large F=\mathbb{Q}(\{a^{1/r}:a,r\in\mathbb{N}\}),$$
or if you want to allow "radicals" of negative integers, an element of the larger field
$$\large L=F(\{e^{2\pi i/n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}).$$
Then no, there are many logarithms with "radical" base and argument that are not themselves "radicals". First, observe that any element of $L$ is an algebraic number (there are algebraic numbers that are not elements of $L$, but that is irrelevant to this question). Now apply the **[Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)** to the equation
$$2^{\log_2(3)}=3$$
for example. $2$ and $3$ are algebraic numbers, so that $\log_2(3)$ must either be rational or transcendental. It cannot be rational; otherwise we get
$$\begin{align*}
\log_2(3)&=\frac{n}{m}\\\\
3&=2^{n/m}\\\\
3^m&=2^n
\end{align*}$$
which is impossible by the unique factorization of integers (or put more simply, because the left side is odd and the right side is even). Therefore
$$\log_2(3)$$
is a logarithm with a "radical" base and exponent that is transcendental, and therefore certainly cannot be "radical" itself.